# Prometheus: sum_over_time of a comparison

Tags: prometheus, promql

I would like to get the number of pings that is over 0.07 seconds.

My query goes:

`ping_rtt_mean_seconds{target="myserver"} > BOOL 0.07`

This gives me either 0 and 1 depend on the actual ping rtt time.

How can I sum it up over a period, so that I am able to know the percentage of >70ms over all ping measures (later on)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Prometheus subqueries](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) feature together with [sum_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum_over_time) function. For example, the following query would return the number of per-minute times (see `1m` in square brackets) the `ping_rtt_mean_seconds{target="myserver"}` was bigger than `0.07` during the last hour (see `1h` in square brackets):

```
sum_over_time((
  ping_rtt_mean_seconds{target="myserver"} >bool 0.07
)[1m:1h])
```

If you need calculating the percentage of time when the `ping_rtt_mean_seconds{target="myserver"}` was greater than `0.07`, then just use avg_over_time function:

```
100 * avg_over_time((
  ping_rtt_mean_seconds{target="myserver"} >bool 0.07
)[1m:1h])
```